# How can I transform blocks into a blockdiagonal matrix (NumPy)

Tags: python, numpy

I have three same-size square matrices in NumPy. I would like to combine these to a block-diagonal matrix.

Example:

```
a1 = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
a2 = np.array([[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]])
a3 = np.array([[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]])

r = np.array([[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0],[0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0],[0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3],[0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3],[0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3]])
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

scipy.linalg has a block_diag function to do this automatically

```
>>> a1 = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
>>> a2 = np.array([[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]])
>>> a3 = np.array([[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]])
>>> import scipy.linalg
>>> scipy.linalg.block_diag(a1, a2, a3)
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3]])
>>> r = np.array([[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0],[0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0],[0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3],[0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3],[0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3]])
>>> (scipy.linalg.block_diag(a1, a2, a3)  == r).all()
True
```

Comment: It would be nice if this were available in numpy (without requiring another dependency).

Comment: scipy is built on top of numpy. I think `scipy.array` should work in substantially the same fashion as `numpy.array`.

Answer (score 4):

Since these answers, `numpy` has added a `block` function

```
In [695]: A=np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
In [696]: B=np.arange(10,14).reshape(2,2)
In [698]: C = np.zeros((3,2),int)

In [699]: np.block([[A,C],[C.T,B]])
Out[699]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  0,  0],
       [ 7,  8,  9,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 12, 13]])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want this particular array `r`, perhaps the easiest way would be:

```
r=np.kron(np.diag([1,2,3]),np.ones((3,3),dtype='int'))
```

If `a1`, `a2`, `a3` can be arbitrary 2-dimensional arrays, then perhaps the easiest way is:

```
a1=np.asmatrix(a1)
a2=np.asmatrix(a2)
a3=np.asmatrix(a3)
z=np.asmatrix(np.zeros((3,3)))
r=np.asarray(np.bmat('a1, z, z; z, a2, z; z, z, a3'))
```

An alternative slower method is:

```
r=(np.kron([[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],a1)   
   +np.kron([[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]],a2)
   +np.kron([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,1]],a3))
```

Answer (score 1):

For those that want to make diagonal matrix containing `M` for `N` times:

```py
from scipy.linalg import block_diag

M = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
N = 3

block_diag(*(M for _ in range(N)))
```