# PyTorch Matrix Product

Tags: python, pytorch

This is the standard batch matrix multiplication:

```
import torch
a = torch.arange(12, dtype=torch.float).view(2,3,2)
b = torch.arange(12, dtype=torch.float).view(2,3,2) - 1
c = a.matmul(b.transpose(-1,-2))
a,b,c

>> 
(tensor([[[ 0.,  1.],
          [ 2.,  3.],
          [ 4.,  5.]],
 
         [[ 6.,  7.],
          [ 8.,  9.],
          [10., 11.]]]),
 tensor([[[-1.,  0.],
          [ 1.,  2.],
          [ 3.,  4.]],
 
         [[ 5.,  6.],
          [ 7.,  8.],
          [ 9., 10.]]]),
 tensor([[[  0.,   2.,   4.],
          [ -2.,   8.,  18.],
          [ -4.,  14.,  32.]],
 
         [[ 72.,  98., 124.],
          [ 94., 128., 162.],
          [116., 158., 200.]]]))
```

This is the one that I have:

```
e = a.view(6,2)
f = b.view(6,2)
g = e.matmul(f.transpose(-1,-2))
e,f,g

>>
(tensor([[ 0.,  1.],
         [ 2.,  3.],
         [ 4.,  5.],
         [ 6.,  7.],
         [ 8.,  9.],
         [10., 11.]]),
 tensor([[-1.,  0.],
         [ 1.,  2.],
         [ 3.,  4.],
         [ 5.,  6.],
         [ 7.,  8.],
         [ 9., 10.]]),
 tensor([[  0.,   2.,   4.,   6.,   8.,  10.],
         [ -2.,   8.,  18.,  28.,  38.,  48.],
         [ -4.,  14.,  32.,  50.,  68.,  86.],
         [ -6.,  20.,  46.,  72.,  98., 124.],
         [ -8.,  26.,  60.,  94., 128., 162.],
         [-10.,  32.,  74., 116., 158., 200.]]))
```

It's obvious that `g` covers `c`. I want to know **if there is an efficient way to retrieve/slice `c` from `g`.** Note that such retrieving/slicing method should generalize well to any shape of `a` and `b`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting diagonal blocks from a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831417/extracting-diagonal-blocks-from-a-numpy-array)

Comment: I think my answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. We can just slice `g` with fancy indexing. We just extract the matrix multiplication result within the same batch:

```
g = g.view(2,3,2,3)
res = g[range(2),:,range(2),:]
res
```