# Staggering matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a matrix G.

I want to make a block matrix

```
 G  Gz
 Gz G
```

in python where Gz is all 0 matrix with same size as G.

All my attempts are leading to crashes.

This is part of my code

```
Gz=[row[:] for row in G]
Gz=np.zeros
G = np.array(G).reshape(-1,nvar)
Gz= np.array(Gz).reshape(-1,nvar)

GGz=np.vstack(G,Gz)
GzG=np.vstack(Gz,G)
GG=np.hstack(GGz,GzG)
```

This is the error message I get :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-56968a80ac64> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('time', '', "G1 = []\nh1 = []\nG = 
[]\nh = []\n#print(G)\nfor i in range(n):\n    for j in range(n):\n        k 
= n*i + j\n       # print('hello0')\n       # print(n)\n       # 
print('hello1')\n       # print(i)\n       # print('hello2')\n       # 
print(j)\n       # print('hello3')\n       # print(k)\n       # exit()\n        
# -b_ij <= 0\n        G.append([0]*nvar)\n        G1.append([0]*nvar)\n\n        
#print(len(G))\n        #print(G)\n        #print('hello3')\n        G[-1] 
[k] = -1\n        G1[-1][k] = -1\n\n        #print(len(G))\n        
#print(G)\n        h.append([0])\n        h1.append([0])\n\n        # b_ij 
<= 1\n        G.append([0]*nvar)\n        G[-1][k] = 1\n        
h.append([1])\n        G1.append([0]*nvar)\n        G1[-1][k] = 1\n        
h1.append([1])\n        # u_i + v_j - b_ij <= 1\n        
G.append([0]*nvar)\n        G[-1][k] = -1\n        G[-1][n**2 + i] = 1\n        
G[-1][n**2 + n + j] = 1\n        h.append([1])\n        
G1.append([0]*nvar)\n        G1[-1][k] = -1\n        G1[-1][n**2 + i] = 1\n
```

It continues as

```
   G1[-1][n**2 + n + j] = 1\n        h1.append([1])\n        # b_ij - u_i <= 
  0\n        G.append([0]*nvar)\n        G[-1][k] = 1\n        G[-1][n**2 + 
  i] 
  = -1\n        h.append([0])\n        G1.append([0]*nvar)\n        G1[-1] 
[k]
```

It continues as

```
= 1\n        G1[-1][n**2 + i] = -1\n        h1.append([0])\n        # u_i 
 <= 
 1\n        G.append([0]*nvar)\n        G[-1][n**2 + i] = 1\n        
 h.append([1])\n        G1.append([0]*nvar)\n        G1[-1][n**2 + i] = 1\n        
 h1.append([1])\n        # b_ij - v_j <= 0\n        G.append([0]*nvar)\n        
 G[-1][k] = 1\n        G[-1][n**2 + n + j] = -1\n        h.append([0])\n        
 G1.append([0]*nvar)\n        G1[-1][k] = 1\n        G1[-1][n**2 + n + j] = 
 -1\n        h1.append([0])\n        # v_j <= 1\n        
  G.append([0]*nvar)\n
```

It continues as

```
 G[-1][n**2 + n + j] = 1\n        h.append([1])\n        
 G1.append([0]*nvar)\n        G1[-1][n**2 + n + j] = 1\n        
 h1.append([1])\n        \n#print(h)\nGz=[row[:] for row in 
 G]\nGz=np.zeros\nG = np.array(G).reshape(-1,nvar)\nGz= 
 np.array(Gz).reshape(-1,nvar)\nh = np.array(h).reshape(-1,1)\nG1 = 
 np.array(G).reshape(-1,nvar)\nh1 = 
 np.array(h).reshape(-1,1)\n\nhh=np.vstack((h,h1))\nhh =
```

It continues as

```
np.array(hh).reshape(-1,1)\nprint(G.shape)\n#print(Gz.shape)\n 
\n#GGz=np.vstack( 
G,Gz)\n#GzG=np.vstack(Gz,G)\n#GG=np.hstack((,np.vstack(Gz,G1)))\n\n#GG = 
np.array(G).reshape(-1,nvar)")
```

It continues as

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in 
run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
2118             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
2119             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2120                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
2121             return result
2122 

<decorator-gen-61> in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)
```

It continues as

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
194 
195         if callable(arg):
```

It continues as

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\execution.py in 
time(self, line, cell, local_ns)
1175         else:
1176             st = clock2()
-> 1177             exec(code, glob, local_ns)
1178             end = clock2()
1179             out = None

<timed exec> in <module>()

ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

Comment: You have so many missing parentheses in this code it's not even  funny. Please post code you've actually tried running. And post the complete error you get, formatted properly. All in the question please: don't respond in comments.

Comment: While you're at it, please explain what each line of the code. What you've posted looks nonsensical enough to be a real mystery.

Comment: It looks to me like you're just looking for [scipy.linalg.block_diag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154253/how-can-i-transform-blocks-into-a-blockdiagonal-matrix-numpy/4155943#4155943).  Is that right?

Comment: @DSM yes I am also trying to vertically and horizontally stack in addition to block stack.

Comment: I tried BlownhitherMa's code it still throws up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.zeros` is a function that takes shape tuple and return matrix of zeros. Following your logic, it would be `Gz=np.zeros(G.shape)`.
In addition to that, I would prefer to generated 4-tile matrix and assigns G to 2 of them.

```
# G = np.random.random((2, 2))
m, n = G.shape
GG = np.zeros((m * 2, n * 2))           # 4 tiles
GG[m:, n:] = G                          # assign left-top
GG[:m, :n] = G                          # assign right-bottom

print(GG)
# [[0.16518374 0.83519636 0.         0.        ]
#  [0.76530177 0.21199601 0.         0.        ]
#  [0.         0.         0.16518374 0.83519636]
#  [0.         0.         0.76530177 0.21199601]]
```

Comment: why does this not work? I am trying to stack two vectors.

      m1, n1 = h.shape
      hh = np.zeros((m1 * 2,n1))           # 2 tiles
      hh[m:, :] = h                          # assign left-top
      hh[:m, :] = h                          # assign right-bottom

Comment: @Turbo The code in the comment use `m1` and `m` at the same time and it is confusing. I guess use `hh[m1:, :] = h` would help?

Comment: does not work

m1, n1 = h.shape
hh = np.zeros((m1 * 2,n1))           # 2 tiles
hh[m1:, :] = h                          # assign left-top
hh[:m1, :] = h                          # assign right-bottom

Comment: @Turbo Does it give errors or what is the desire result? ( By the way, why `np.zeros((m1 * 2,n1))` instead of `n1 * 2`? It doesn't help your original request

Comment: I am also trying to horizontally and vertically stack in addition to diagonal stack.

Comment: Your current code stacks two `h` which is equivalent to simply `np.vstack([h, h])`. And I do not see any error raised

Comment: Do you know what this means? ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-3c6057213311> in <module>()
      1 E = np.zeros((n**2,nvar))
----> 2 E[:n**2,:n**2] = np.diag(np.ones(n**2))
      3 b = np.zeros(n**2).reshape(n**2,-1)
      4 b[:n**2] = M.reshape(n**2,-1)
      5 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (225,225) into shape (225,15)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170472/discussion-between-blownhither-ma-and-turbo).

Comment: Do you know how to print matrix size? len(A) does not help.

Comment: `np.shape(matrix)` or `matrix.shape` if it is numpy matrix

Comment: Would you also know this? AttributeError: 'cvxopt.base.matrix' object has no attribute 'astype'

Comment: I try G = cop.matrix(G.astype(float)) here.

Comment: @Turbo `np.array(G).astype(float)` because numpy has `astype` function while I'm not sure about `cvxopt` (chatroom preferred because this is not related to the original post