# numpy: split 2d numpy array and then create 2d diagonal block array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose, I got a 2D (n \times 2*n) numpy array like below,

```
dat = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
```

I want to split it into two 2d array equally, and then create a 2d diagonal block array, like below,

```
a = dat[:,0:2]
b = dat[:,2:]
result = np.block([
    [a,               np.zeros((2, 2))],
    [np.zeros((2, 2)), b              ]
])
```

Is there any better way in numpy that I dont need to specify this part "np.zero((n,n))"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scipy.linalg.block_diag`

```
>>> import scipy.linalg
>>> scipy.linalg.block_diag(a, b)
array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
       [5, 6, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 4],
       [0, 0, 7, 8]])
```

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154253/how-can-i-transform-blocks-into-a-blockdiagonal-matrix-numpy) post